# IKVMC omits some classes when converting JAR file into .DLL

Tags: netty, ikvm

I am trying to convert the netty-common jar to a dll using ikvmc.

I have downloaded ikvm and I am using the command:

```
ikvmc ..\netty-common...jar -target:library
```

from the ikvm\bin directory.  I do not receive any error, but the resulting dll is missing many of the classes contained in the jar file.

Are there switches that I must also provide in order to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

There was not a problem with the generation of any classes.  Visual Studio doesn't show classes that are only package visible.  The tool ildasm does show the classes are present.

The source of my problem however was something different, which I will explain here if it's useful to someone in the future.

Netty seems to have an unsafe problem under open jdk (which ikvm uses).  To solve my problem, I used the following line before any Netty operations:

```
    System.setProperty ("io.netty.tryUnsafe", "false");
```